# Speed is reduced substantially when writing to serial port

Tags: python, pygame, pyserial

Using pygame to read info from controller, but when I add `arduinoData.write(str.encode(ALL_DATA))` it reduces the speed a lot, what can I do?

The line is added almost at the bottom. Is it the placement of the line; it is definitely working but doesn't send updates as fast as if I wouldn't write to serial.

```
import sys
import serial
import pygame
import time

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

A0_value = '0'
A1_value = '0'
A2_value = '0'
A3_value = '0'
A4_value = '0'
A5_value = '0'
A6_value = '0'
B2 = '0'
B3 = '0'
B4 = '0'
B5 = '0'
global axis_data 

## 
arduinoData = serial.Serial('COM8',9600)

##

def main():
    global axis_data , button_data
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 700))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Joystick example")

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    joysticks = {}

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True  # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop.

                if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
                    print("Joystick button pressed.")
                    if event.button == 0:
                        joystick = joysticks[event.instance_id]
                        if joystick.rumble(0, 0.7, 500):
                            print(
                                "Rumble effect played on joystick {}".format(
                                    event.instance_id
                                )
                            )

                if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
                    print("Joystick button released.")

                # Handle hotplugging
                if event.type == pygame.JOYDEVICEADDED:
                    # This event will be generated when the program starts for every
                    # joystick, filling up the list without needing to create them manually.
                    joy = pygame.joystick.Joystick(event.device_index)
                    joysticks[joy.get_instance_id()] = joy
                    print("Joystick {} connencted".format(joy.get_instance_id()))

                if event.type == pygame.JOYDEVICEREMOVED:
                    del joysticks[event.instance_id]
                    print("Joystick {} disconnected".format(event.instance_id))




        for joystick in joysticks.values():
            axes = joystick.get_numaxes()
            #print("Number of axes: {}".format(axes))
            axis_str = [''] * axes
            button_data = ""
            axis_data = ""



            for i in range(axes):
                axis = joystick.get_axis(i)
                axis_int = int(axis*100)
                axis_str[i] = str(axis_int)
                axis_data = axis_str[i] + "," + axis_data 
                #print("Axis {} value: {}".format(i, axis)) 
            
            #print(axis_data)
            buttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
            #print("Number of buttons: {}".format(buttons))
            button_str = ['0'] * buttons

            for i in range(buttons):
                button = joystick.get_button(i)
                button_str[i] = str(button)
                #print("Button {} value: {}".format(i, button))
                button_data = button_str[i] + "," + button_data
            
            #print(button_data)
            ALL_DATA = axis_data + button_data
            ALL_DATA = ALL_DATA[:-1] + "!"
            print(ALL_DATA)
        arduinoData.write(str.encode(ALL_DATA))

        
            
       # pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    # If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
    # on exit if running from IDLE.
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The slowdown is being caused by the `arduinoData.write()` call blocking the event processing loop until it completes. To work around that you could use create a separate thread to the writing or use the experimental [`asyncio` support](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#module-serial.aio) the `pyserial` module has.

Comment: Using a higher baud rate would reduce the time taken to send updates.  Choosing a more compact representation for your updates (for example, using bits in a byte rather than two ASCII characters for each button state) would also help.

Answer (score 7):

Writing to serial at 9600 baud is really quite slow.  Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647857/time-to-send-32kb-over-9600-baud-serial) on baud-rate send-time, to send each letter is a bit more than 1 millisecond (roughly).  Note that at 60 FPS, each frame is allowed ~17 milliseconds.  The code is writing this data as a string, so probably it's taking quite some milliseconds, every loop.

A *really* easy win is to simply use a faster baud-rate.  You could at least try `230400` for a 24x speed-up.

Also *almost never* do we send real-time data as strings.  You could use the Python [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to pack all the various joystick readings into binary data, which would be much more compact.  Especially if you treat button  states as single bits, and don't need high-resolution on the joystick position.

And finally, your code could use a thread to perform the serial communications, writing in parallel to the main PyGame loop.  This works well on "IO Bound" operations.